# Decompose $[0,1]$ into countably many non-measurable sets .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can any one give me any idea about how to decompose $[0,1]$ into countably many non-measurable sets?
Thanks.

Comment: Working much harder than in the answer below, it is possible to partition the interval into a continuum of sets with inner measure $0$ and outer measure $1$. See [this discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/) on mathoverflow.

Comment: @user63664 : in the answer you accepted, the set is called a "Vitali set", in case you want to look up more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method:

Find out a way to divide an interval into two non-measurable sets (which means that you should know how to find *one* non-measurable set, and then its complement is also non-measurable).

Next divide $[0,1]$ into the following parts: $\{0\}$ and the rest we split into intervals $\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$. Each of these intervals we cut to two non-measurable parts, and we know how to do that. Lastly, the singleton $\{0\}$ should be added to one of these non-measurable sets, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S \subset [0,1]$ be such that for all $y \in [0,1]$, there exists a unique $x \in S$ such that $x - y \in \mathbb Q$. Then the sets $\{ (S + \{q \} ) \cap [0,1], q \in \mathbb Q \}$ ($+$ is the Minkowski sum) form a partition of $[0,1]$ and none of these sets are measurable.

Comment: is this a "Vitali set"?  If so, that info would help the OP in case s/he wanted to search for more properties of it.

Comment: It is indeed a Vitali set, thanks for pointing it out.